# Understanding Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have downloaded the android source code. I am  going through Bluetooth part. I wanted to know how the createBond function in framework level will internally call the pin functionality. (Entire android Bluetooth architecture flow). I was going through the code but was not able to understand as I am a beginner. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. This question is quite broad--and if you're a "beginner", diving into the Android source code probably isn't a great place to start. It's not clear what you're actually asking, at least so far.

Comment: I wanted to know at which part of android architecture it is possible to find the method used for bluetooth pairing (Legacy or SSP Pairing) in android source code. Please help me to find the code in android source code.

Comment: I wanted to know how LMP feature mask can be used to select between Legacy pairing and SSP pairing in android source code. I also wanted to know what is LMP feature mask and what is its use.

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the functionality of how createBond works internally in the and what are its different states in the following java class.

/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/btservice/BondStateMachine.java

In above class please check private inner class PendingCommandState and you can figure our rest by yourself how Android handles different variants for pairing process.